Sum statement involving a varchar column
Within the database I am working in, the column Notes is datatype varchar with a date value and a note placed right after (Example: 05/15/2024: This is the note.) There are two main comments I have extracted into another column using a Case When expression which is as follows:
Case When notes like "%Automatic%' then 'Automatic' ELSE 'Manual' End) as 'Status'

I am attempting to create a SUM CASE WHEN expression to give me the total number of Automatic rows and Manual rows but I am encountering a few error messages most commonly:

Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

which I suspect is because of the varchar datatype in notes section.
Is there a way to sum via the 'Status' Column that has been created through the case when expression?
Code as follows:
SELECT a.CustomerID
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END) AS 'STATUS?'
FROM CARS.DBO.REVIEW AS A
GROUP BY A.CustomerID

Any insight would be appreciated

What do you expect the sum of a bunch of string to be?

do THEN 1 ELSE 0 and that will SUM

What is 'AUTOMATIC' + 'Manual' (addition not concatenation) exactly? What is 'A' + 'M'? 'N'? 'Ž'? Summing strings doesn't make sense.

I suspect that you are looking to perform conditional aggregation, which just places the conditional CASE of IIF() expression inside the aggregation expression like SUM() or COUNT().
SELECT
    A.CustomerID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 1 END) AS Automatic,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.NOTES NOT LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 1 END) AS Manual  
FROM CARS.DBO.REVIEW A
GROUP BY A.CustomerID

Withing each conditional aggregation expression, the THEN 1 results are counted, while the implied ELSE NULL results are not. You could also use SUM() together with an explicit ELSE 0, but I believe COUNT() more clearly shows the intent.
Results:



CustomerID
Automatic
Manual




101
2
1


102
0
2



Or perhaps you are looking to perform a GROUP BY after wrapping up the transmission type logic in a CROSS APPLY:
SELECT CustomerID, T.Type, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM CARS.DBO.REVIEW A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS Type
) T
GROUP BY A.CustomerID, T.Type

A CROSS APPLY is a convenient way of calculating a value once, and referencing that value elsewhere multiple times without repeating the expression.
Results:



CustomerID
Type
Number




101
AUTOMATIC
2


101
MANUAL
1


102
MANUAL
2



See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both.


I am attempting to create a SUM CASE WHEN expression to give me the total number of Automatic rows and Manual rows....

To get the total by transmission type, you want something like this:
SELECT CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS STATUS, COUNT(*) AS STATUS_COUNT
FROM CARS.DBO.REVIEW A
GROUP BY CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END

I wouldn't suggest this approach, but technically this works too:
SELECT CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END AS STATUS, 
SUM(CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTO%' THEN 1 ELSE 1 END) AS STATUS_COUNT
FROM CARS.DBO.REVIEW A
GROUP BY CASE WHEN A.NOTES LIKE '%AUTOMATIC%' THEN 'AUTOMATIC' ELSE 'MANUAL' END

